# Are pure and traditional Ajax Requests possible on native / hybrid mobile apps?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, sencha-touch, cross-domain

I know that using JSONP thechnique http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP we can kinda make a cross domain Ajax Request.

But for this question that doesn't count as "pure and traditional".

**I am only wondering if for native / hybrid apps also applies the "Same Origin Policy"**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

There seems to be a lot of confusion in this matter.

A friend of mine swears that he connected Sencha Touch 2.3.1 + PhoneGap 3 to his back-end with "Ajax" proxies which I find hard to believe (proxies should be JSONP IMO), or this only requires special server config since Same Origin Policy is never applied 'cos browsers never get involved?

I know this kinda question might not be in the spirit of SO but I think a good answer on this subject would help a lot of people since I've not been able to find one.

Best regards @code4jhon

Comment: I don't believe this is possible because requests from a mobile device have the origin `file://` and are basically the same as opening an html document from your desktop. I don't believe it is possible to run any type of service from a mobile device that would act as a server to send requests from a specific origin other than `file://`

Comment: @Dawson Loudon So that means that for consuming a REST service from a SenchaTouch + PhoneGap it is mandatory to use JSONP technique ?
Or how do you comunicate with your back-end when developing PhoneGap apps?

Comment: @Dawson Loudon So far I have a Java Jersey REST application and a Sencha Touch 2.3.1 + PhoneGap3 app, and I'm wondering what is the elegant way to communicate ...

Comment: If I have control of the backend it's usually a PHP script I am connecting to, so I set the `allow-origin` header to all and I use `jsonp` for the ajax requests. If security is an issue I make use of things like https, api keys, session tokens and basic auth.

Comment: Native apps are not bound by the same origin policy (since it's a browser feature), and can request data from wherever they choose.  The server doesn't even have to be aware of that nature.  It's just responding to a request like it always does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhoneGap apps run in webview not in browser, so cross origin is not an issue with PhoneGap apps, you can perform AJAX calls to any URL.

The only thing to care of is that there is a white list parameter "access origin" in config used to restrict the access to some specific URLs.

For older PhoneGap versions, the default setting for access origin was localhost, but now it is set by default to "*" which allows access to any URL.

No need for JSONP or cors headers with PhoneGap.

Comment: Any special configuration on the server side ?

Comment: I've used phonegap and ajax calls to communicate with java or php servers and never had to change anything on server side.