# App Development - JSONP or Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: http, jquery-mobile, http-headers, sencha-touch

I would like to develop a mobile client for my website. The client should call some json services to receive the data. It will failed cause cross origin policy, but that is ok. 
I can use JSONP or setting the header of the response to

```
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
```

But whats the best way to support mobile client? With both solution I can't define which client has access to my services. So everybody who knows the "API" can write his own client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I had to deal with a similar reasoning.

1.- You should implement some server-side security.

2.- If your "mobile client" is a native or hybrid (packaged with phonegap/cordova framework) application you don't need to use JSONP you can use standard Ajax requests.

3.- If your "mobile client" is going to be an html5 javascript css3 based app and is going to be in a different domain I would choose JSONP. Because of security and it just seems more natural for me.

I asked this question: [Are pure and traditional Ajax Requests possible on native / hybrid mobile apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915443/are-pure-and-traditional-ajax-requests-possible-on-native-hybrid-mobile-apps)

Phonegap site: http://phonegap.com/

For security in the server side I used to use Spring Security Core I loved its simplicity. http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/ (I used Grails in that time)

best regards I hope it helps